# Too small values to be displayed by gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, bar-chart

I'm encountering a problem using gnuplot to display some distribution data (in the form of bar charts).
Because of the very high values in my data, the smallest ones cannot be displayed.
For example with these values:

```
10 1
20 4
21 24
22 77
23 177
24 636
25 1700
26 3433
27 5160
28 7462
29 7883
30 6652
31 4155
32 1989
33 797
34 170
```

Gnuplot do not display the bars corresponding to 10 and 20 because they are way too small comparatively to the maximum.

Is there a way to display them, just a little bit, other than using a logarithmic scale ?

I was especially thinking to a kind of glowing effect at the top of the bars whose values are not null, can it be done using gnuplot ?

Here are the few lines I use to display my data

```
set style data boxes
set style fill solid 0.1
plot 'distribution.dat'
```

And here is what I get for the moment:
[distribution bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaBDc.png)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe use the "zeroaxis" representation rather than a plot border, and increase the linewidth used to draw boxes.

```
set style data boxes
set style fill solid 0.1
set xrange [0:*]
set yrange [-100:*]
set xzeroaxis
set yzeroaxis
set tics nomirror
unset key
unset border

plot $DATA linewidth 1.5
```

[image]